# How to set line-endings in git for local copy

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I'm working on a project where we pull repos then check for various legal issues. I cannot modify the external projects, but do have complete control over my local machine (Ubuntu). Am running into line-ending issues and wondering if there's a a way to force the local copies to adhere to LF for all files (except for windows-specific files) as of now we do not plan on pushing changes, just scanning the repos.

Answer (score 0):

To have Git guess what's best for you (i.e. LF for line endings on Linux), do a

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
# Configure Git to ensure line endings in files you checkout are correct for Linux
```

On a "per repository" basis, you could set this in the repos `.gitattributes` file, but as I understood, you don't want to change the repos. For a more detailed description see https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings